# Flask: how to detect a user leaving a page?

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a Flask web app, and I want to call a function from views.py when a user leaves one specific page (closes the page or goes to another page). How do I do this?

Comment: You don't. Seriously, there is no way to do this in a remotely reliable way. The browser has completely closed the connection long before the user goes away. The user might even have no internet at that point for all you can know. But if you insist on trying that, JS running in the browser is the only tool that might help you know that - unreliably ofc.

Comment: Or you can make use of the html meta tag for refresh, embed an iframe that reloads all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a websocket (i.e see https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#connection-events). You can register a disconnect handler function.